# What are the default file permissions in CentOS?

Tags: linux, centos, files, permissions, rhel

What are the default file permissions in CentOS 5, CentOS 6 and CentOS 7?
Is there any difference in the default file permissions between these OSs?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Default permissions are based on your `umask` setting.

RHEL 6.6:

```
# umask
0022
```

I don't believe that has changed by default - can't find anything authoritative.

umask is something that you should set as part of the default profile.

Comment: As pointed out by @DarkHeart , it's correct. Are you facing any permissions issues?. If yes, kindly post it so that the real issue can be hit.